# Strange float? Pointer to a float in a struct

Tags: c, struct, floating-point

first time posting here

I'm currently porting some code for an embedded device. Basically getting everything to work with a new compiler (AVR-GCC) from an out-of-date existing proprietary compiler

I've come across this strange looking (to me anyway!) variable in a struct. I can't work out what it is with the parentheses. It is in a struct which is used for raw values:

```
float   (*tc)( float value );
```

My IDE highlights 'value' as a compiler keyword, just like 'float' so I don't know if this is AVR-GCC specific?

This is then used in a function which has a float argument called 'reading' and it tries to return the following:

```
    return (raw[rCN3].tc)( reading );
```

The line above actually causes the program to attempt to access out of bounds memory.

I haven't seen code like this before so was wondering if anyone could help me decipher it? It worked with the old compiler but is causing a problem with AVR-GCC

Thanks in advance. Alex

Comment: It's a function pointer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: "My IDE highlights 'value' as a compiler keyword" <- it's not one in C. Perhaps it uses the same highlighter for several languages.

Comment: BTW: there are excess parentheses in the statement, `return raw[rCN3].tc( reading );` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! I should really have spotted that as a function pointer. Thanks for the link too

Answer (score 1):

This is a function pointer. It points to a function that returns a float value and that has a float parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) `float (*tc)( float value )` is a `function pointer` to a function taking a float as a parameter, returning a float

2) 'value' is a keyword in C# and may also be in other languages; hence its highlighting. Check your editor language settings.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm using AVR Studio which is based on Visual Studio so may have C# highlighting enabled.

Answer (score 0):

That is a function pointer variable.

`tc` is a pointer to a function, which takes a single `float` as argument and returns a `float.

The reason it accesses out of bounds memory is *probably* because `rCN3` is out of bounds for the array `raw`.

Comment: Thanks! I should really have spotted this....haven't used function pointers in quite a long time. Thanks for prompt response

Answer (score 0):

That is a function pointer.

It means that `tc` holds the address of a function accepting a single `float` argument, and returning a `float` value.

For instance, you could set it to the standard library's [`sinf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sin) function, like so:

```
somestruct.tc = sinf;

somestruct.tc(3.14159265f / 2);  /* This will return roughly 1.0f. */
```

Also, the ever-useful [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) says:

> declare tc as pointer to function (float) returning float

Comment: Great link. Many thanks for your help
I will definitely be using cdecl in the future :)